# IO slow on Android?

Tags: java, android, io, fat

This should show the internal and external memory speeds, but unfortunately it says it's 0.02 or 0.04 MB/s? Is this an enormous inefficiency in Android, or coding error?

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonStorageSpeed).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                double SDSpeed = MBPSTest(getExternalCacheDir()); // /sdcard
                double MemSpeed = MBPSTest(getCacheDir());        // /data/data
                final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisContext)
                .setTitle("Memory speed")
                .setMessage( "Internal:"+String.valueOf(MemSpeed) + "\n"  + "SD:"+String.valueOf(SDSpeed))
                .create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });




/**
     * Test MB/s write speed in some directory.
     * Writes 4MB, deletes it after.
     * @param outdir
     * @return
     */
    private double MBPSTest(File outDir) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            for (int fnum = 0; fnum < 1024; fnum++) {
                File out = new File(outDir,"TESTspeed"+String.valueOf(fnum));
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);

                //Write 4k files
                for (int i=0; i < 1024; i++) {
                    fos.write(65);//A
                    fos.write(69);//E
                    fos.write(73);//I
                    fos.write(79);//O
                }
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                //System.out.println("Wrote file.");
            }
            //Wrote 4MB

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrote External at: "+String.valueOf(4.0 / (elapsed/1000.0) )+" MB/S", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        //Clean up:
        for (int fnum = 0; fnum < 1024; fnum++) {
            File out = new File(outDir, "TESTspeed"+String.valueOf(fnum));
            out.delete();
        }
        // 4 MB / (seconds)
        return 4.0 / (elapsed/1000.0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as the overhead Jonathon mentioned of opening and closing the file a lot, you're also calling `write(int)` for every single byte.

Either use `write(byte[])` with a big buffer, or use a `BufferedOutputStream` to wrap the `FileOutputStream`. There *may* be some buffering in `FileOutputStream` already, but equally there may not be. You may well find that once you've got fewer write operations (but still the same amount of data) it's *much* faster.

Comment: That increases write speed significantly - 0.13 MB/s internal. I forgot about that, it's been awhile since I did that in Java. Come to think of it, I remember copying many small files was incredibly slow on desktop too for some reason, so maybe this benchmark is accurate for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You're introducing a ton of overhead here:

```
        for (int fnum = 0; fnum < 1024; fnum++) {
            File out = new File(outDir,"TESTspeed"+String.valueOf(fnum));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);

            //Write 4k files
            for (int i=0; i < 1024; i++) {
                fos.write(65);//A
                fos.write(69);//E
                fos.write(73);//I
                fos.write(79);//O
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            //System.out.println("Wrote file.");
        }
        //Wrote 4MB
```

You're closing and opening the file every 4k (1024 times per file).  Instead you should open it just *once* outside the loop.

This is still far from being a scientific test. You're making a bunch of API calls that aren't going to show the real speed of the device. Also, you might have a bunch of filesystem re-sizing overhead going on.

A better method might be:

- Open the file
- Write the desired size of data
- Seek to the beginning of the file
- Flush
- Start timer
- Write desired size of data in as big of a chunk as possible
- Stop timer
- Cleanup

Comment: It is writing multiple fairly-small files - is this too different from normal usage?

Comment: Well, I suppose that's a question for you: What are you trying to test?  Many small things will almost always be slower than one large one.